# How can I use Swashbuckle's SwaggerUI to display a static swagger.json file instead of SwaggerGen's dynamically created definiton?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, openapi, swashbuckle

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application, targeting the .NET Core 2.1 framework.  This application serves a RESTful API and returns JSON data.

Using the interactive, web-based SwaggerGen in [SwaggerHub](https://swagger.io/tools/swaggerhub/), I've created an API definition document and saved it in JSON format as 'swagger.json' in a folder in my ASP.NET Core MVC application project.

[image: Manually created 'swagger.json' API definition file]

Since I've already defined the API, I don't need to run SwaggerGen in my application.  I'd just like SwaggerUI to display the static 'swagger.json' file I've created.

I've read the Swashbuckle documentation as well as several "How to get started with Swashbuckle" tutorials, but they all assume that SwaggerGen will be used to dynamically create the Swagger API documentation from my API.

I've added the 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore' NuGet package to my application's dependencies.

[image: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore NuGet package]

In the Configure() method in my application's Startup.cs class, I've added the UseSwaggerUI directive:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
```

When I run my application in Visual Studio, I get a normal blank page.

[image: ASP.NET Core MVC application running]

Per the Swashbuckle documentation, the SwaggerUI-formatted API documentation should be available at the relative '/swagger' path, assuming that SwaggerGen had been added and had dynamically generated the API definition (file?).

GETting the relative '/swagger' path produces a '400 Bad Request' error.

[image: Requesting the Swagger documentation produces '400 Bad Request' error]

Q: Would SwaggerGen produce its own 'swagger.json' file, and if so, where would it create this file?

Q: Is there a way to tell SwaggerUI where to find and display my manually created 'swagger.json' API definition file?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? Pretty much the whole point is to have the swagger.json generated automatically, so it's kept in sync with changes you make to your API. If you were to use a static swagger.json, you would also then need to remember to regen it any time you make a change, which I can assure you that you will not remember to do. Is this a performance thing? The JSON is only generated when it's requested, which means it's only going to impact the API docs, not your site as whole. Even then, it's not exactly *arduous* to gen.

Comment: Hi, @ChrisPratt.  Swagger (well, SmartBear, actually) has a number of API-first tools, including one that can generate application source code from an API definition.  If we generate code from an API definition, then we've flipped the "order of operations" and changed the priority from code to design.  This also guarantees that changes to the API definition are never forgotten.  They are made first and are what results in the source code.

Comment: Design first is a good approach. but @ChrisPratt makes us think `Why would you want to do this?` Swashbuckle is a sledgehammer to fix a swiss watch. Why use that? was that the "easy" NuGet package option?

Comment: @DougWilson I guest my point is that Swagger UI is just a SPA. If you're not combining it with the Gen, then it doesn't need to be part of your project at all. Just throw it up somewhere and feed it your static JSON files. Done.

Comment: I explained why I want to do it, Helder.We're generating code from the API definition using Swagger CodeGe, not generating the API definition from the code.  Swashbuckle [docs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) state that it "consists of multiple components that can be used together or individually dependening [sic] on your needs".  So the question remains how can I use Swashbuckle's SwaggerUI to display a static swagger.json file instead of SwaggerGen's dynamically created definiton?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, our use case is microservices, each with its own API definition.  They are intended to run independently in Docker containers, so being self-contained and self-sufficient is important.  I don't want to have to include a Node server just to display SwaggerUi documents, especially since Swashbuckle claims to do this from within ASP.NET Core MVC projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On your local machine, make a small node project, install swagger-ui-dist
2. copy the installed files from node_modules/swagger-ui-dist to your webserver where you host the swagger site
3. Copy your generated swagger.json to the same folder in your webserver
4. Edit index.html and add the url to your json , ex. '/swagger.json'
5. Done

Source

https://yanhan.github.io/posts/2017-11-26-using-swagger-ui-with-any-codebase/

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to use a core website to convert an external EDMX into OpenAPI format and then display it.. so I figured this out

I was able to take [Microsoft's OData sample](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData) and serve a static JSON into the Swasbhuckle-powered SwaggerUI like this:

1. Create a directory in your project, e.g. `generatedjson`
2. Put your json (open api doc) into said folder
3. Enable static files to be served from this folder
4. Within UseSwaggerUI, I added a new SwaggerUI endpoint

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "OData 8.x OpenAPI");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/generatedjson/swagger.json", "SAP Business One");
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    // Test middleware
    app.Use(next => context =>
    {
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint == null)
        {
            return next(context);
        }

        return next(context);
    });

    //app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"generatedjson")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/generatedjson")
    });
}
```

### FWIW - If this is all your site does

Then you may feel free to disable the EDM generation services in `ConfigureServices`

```cs
           services.AddControllers();
                //.AddOData(opt => opt.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(5)
                    //.AddRouteComponents(model0)
                    //.AddRouteComponents("v1", model1)
                    //.AddRouteComponents("v2{data}", model2, services => services.AddSingleton<ODataBatchHandler, DefaultODataBatchHandler>())
                    //.AddRouteComponents("v3", model3)
                    //.Conventions.Add(new MyConvention())
                

            services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell any Swagger-UI where to find the file using the `url` parameter:

- http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/swagger/swagger.json
- http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?url=https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

And that is all you need, you can use any Swagger-UI no need to install swashbuckle if you already generate your definition with SwaggerHub.

---

If you want to host a Swagger-UI yourself just copy the dist folder to your webserver:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist

Comment: Thanks, Helder, but in this case another server (at githubusercontent.com) is being used to serve the Swagger document.  I'm looking for a way to get my ASP.NET Core MVC application to serve it.

Comment: @DougWilson you are serving your Swagger document (static 'swagger.json' file) on your project right? just pass that to any swagger-ui

Comment: `http://petstore.swagger.io/?URL=https://foo.bar/path/to/your/swagger.json`

Comment: Hosting my own copy of swagger-ui to serve my static swagger.json API definition file is a great suggestion.  Thank you, Helder!

Comment: @DougWilson and the swagger-ui you can reduce a lot of what you host if you change a bit https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html#L36-L37 to point those scripts to the cdn:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/swagger-ui

Comment: @RobMcCabe I think that the UI is now case-sensitive,  I corrected  the provided examples showing that it does work